# How can I initialize this array by calling this method?

Tags: java, arrays

for some reason I just can't figure out how I can call the bottom two methods for the variables up top. When i do initalizeString(String[] names); I always get .class expected. Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here on calling the method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class SoftDrinkInventory {

    static final int MAXSIZE = 100;      // maximum size of 100
    private String[] names;             // softdrink names
    private String[] ids;               // softdrink identifications
    private int[] startingInventory;    // starting inventory of the softdrinks
    private int[] finalInventory;       // final inventory of the softdrinks
    private int[] transactionCounts;    // number of transactions per softdrink
    private int trueSize;               // total number of softdrinks

    public SoftDrinkInventory() {

      // call initalizeString for names/ids
      // call initializeInt for inventory/transaction counts

    }

    private void initializeInt(int[] a) {

        a = new int[MAXSIZE];

        for(int i = 0; i <= MAXSIZE; i++) {
            a[i] = 0;
        }

    }

    private void initializeString(String[] s) {

        s = new String[MAXSIZE];

        for(int i = 0; i <= MAXSIZE; i++) {
            s[i] = "";
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your specific problem:  Just use `initializeString(names)` instead of `initalizeString(String[] names)`.  But your program won’t work as expected.  Java passes method parameters by value.  That means that you can reassign the `s` parameter in the `initializeString(String[])` method, but this won’t affect the `names` field.

Furthermore, if you create an `new int[MAXSIZE]`, the array will contain 100 `0` values by default.  You do not have to set them manually.  Last but not least, you should consider to use the Collections framework, especially the `List` interface, instead of arrays.  It’s mutch easier to use and has no significant disadvantages.

Comment: This is an assignment for class, and we're not allowed to use materials that we have not been taught in class before. But in response to your answer, using initalizeString(names) gives me the error of "cannot find symbol - method initalizeString(java.lang.String[]); maybe you meant: initalizeString(String[])

Comment: @user2899245 This error seems to be caused by a typo, but I don’t spot it.  Make sure you spell the method’s name correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Using `initalizeString(String[] names);` is not the correct way to call a method. You do not specify the type when calling a method. Try `initializeString(names);`

Also, you have an off-by-one error in your loops, you should use...

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; i++) {
```

...since arrays are zero-indexed.